# Why is the file output to variable append unrelated file names under the path

Tags: shell

I need to print the last line of file e.g. /path/file to an argument

Content:

```
>tail -n 1 /path/file
74.870 534.1 2187.7 0.000 60.0 32047 5.782 716.573 **
```

The output from command line is correct.

But when I use:

```
arg=`tail -n 1 /path/file`
or arg=$(tail -n 1 /path/file)
echo $arg
```

The output become

```
74.870 534.1 2187.7 0.000 60.0 32047 5.782 716.573 file1 file2 file3 ....
file1 file2 file3 are under /path
```

Seems the ** is translated to something like `ls`?
I don't quite understand the meaning...

How could I get the right $arg here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**` *is getting expanded ,which is resulting in listing all the files in the directory. This is called [Globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).*

When not double or single quoted:

```
echo 74.870 534.1 2187.7 0.000 60.0 32047 5.782 716.573 **
74.870 534.1 2187.7 0.000 60.0 32047 5.782 716.573 file1 file2.....
more files..... and more files......
```

When double quoted:

```
echo "74.870 534.1 2187.7 0.000 60.0 32047 5.782 716.573 **"
74.870 534.1 2187.7 0.000 60.0 32047 5.782 716.573 **
```

or `set -f` before doing `echo` to prevent wild card expansion.